# Adding option in launching option of eclipse .product file to suppress SVN process

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing eclipse application which consists of svn plugins also. On launching my application it process for `SVN Update Cache` in background whose indication is shown in bottom right corner of my application. Manually I can change the the SVN settings from `Preference > Team > SVN`. But I want to do it during building/launching my application.

There is tab in application's `.product` file under `Launching` tab where I can add `VM arguments`.
I want to add following entries under that:

```
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.compute.deep=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.precise.enablements=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.cache=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.persistent.ssh=false
```

When I added these under VM arguments, it is throwing error during launching of applcation:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.preference.decoration.compute.deep=false
```

How should i add these entries?

Comment: *Exactly* how are you adding them now? What are you typing in there?

Comment: I simply added above entries as it is.

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize=2G
-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash
-XX:+ShowMessageBoxOnError
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.compute.deep=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.precise.enablements=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.cache=false
org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.persistent.ssh=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM arguments that are for system properties follow the syntax shown at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html :

**-Dproperty=value**

*Sets a system property value.*

```
If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the string 
in double quotation marks:

java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass
```

So try (because, remember, there are other kinds of VM arguments):

```
-Dorg.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.compute.deep=false
-Dorg.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.precise.enablements=false
-Dorg.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.cache=false
-Dorg.eclipse.team.svn.ui/preference.decoration.enable.persistent.ssh=false
```